# data.table by = xx How do i keep the groups of length 0 when i returns no match

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, subset

I'm trying to work around a problem that has arisen due to the size of my data and that I haven't been able to find an answer to. 
( i.e. [Data.table: how to get the blazingly fast subsets it promises and apply to a second data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263698/data-table-how-to-get-the-blazingly-fast-subsets-it-promises-and-apply-to-a-sec))

This is the dummy data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

adherence <- cbind.data.frame(c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"), c("2013-01-01", "2013-01-01", "2013-01-01", "2013-02-01", "2013-02-01", "2013-02-01"))
names(adherence)[1] <- "ID" 
names(adherence)[2] <- "year"
adherence$year <- ymd(adherence$year)

lsr <- cbind.data.frame(
  c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3"), #ID
  c("2012-03-01", "2012-08-02", "2013-01-06","2012-08-25", "2013-03-22", "2013-09-15", "2011-01-01", "2013-01-05"), #eksd
  c("60", "90", "90", "60", "120", "60", "30", "90") # DDD
)
names(lsr)[1] <- "ID"
names(lsr)[2] <- "eksd"
names(lsr)[3] <- "DDD"

lsr$eksd <- as.Date((lsr$eksd))
lsr$DDD <- as.numeric(as.character(lsr$DDD))
lsr$ENDDATE <- lsr$eksd + lsr$DDD
lsr <- as.data.table(lsr)

adherence <- as.data.table(adherence)
```

I have tried different methods for achieving the result: a cartesian join gives me more than 2*31 rows and won't work. I rewrote everything in data.table and it literally reduced the run speed by days. I've found that if I can get this line to return the desired result I can create a for loop that looks at the "2013-02-01" and 500 other timepoints and achieve my dream (of continuing to another issue). One subset below only takes 15s on my data (so I could run it all in a few hours), but my problem is that it returns only groups with a valued subset. ID:2 is not returned, I think, because the group has no match in i. - reducing the time spend on the operation.

```
lsr[eksd <= as.Date("2013-02-01") & ENDDATE > as.Date("2013-02-01"), sum(as.numeric(ENDDATE - as.Date("2013-02-01"))), keyby = ID]


    ID V1
1:  1 64
2:  3 63
```

Under most circumstances that is clever, but I need the information about the groups with length = 0. (or whatever value - I just need no to drop the ID information). Somehow like this:

```
   ID V1
1:  1 64
2:  2 0
3:  3 63
```

I tried using the tidyr::complete function (as explained here: [dplyr summarise: Equivalent of ".drop=FALSE" to keep groups with zero length in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523131/dplyr-summarise-equivalent-of-drop-false-to-keep-groups-with-zero-length-in)) , but dplyr is way too slow. It takes 7 hours on 0,2% of my data. I'm sure this can be achieved somehow. Any suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: How big is your data?

Comment: @MichaelChirico  - the three row table following "Somehow like this:"

Comment: @minem my lsr has 20 mio rows and 12 columns, the adherence dataset, that I'm trying not to use has 1,5 mio rows of 2 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has asked how to fill in the missing `ID`s which were dropped during the previous aggregation.

Without considering performance issues associated with OP'S aggregation code, one method to complete the `ID`s is to join with the unique `ID`s, directly chained with the previous operation:

```
uid <- sort(unique(lsr$ID))
# OP's code
lsr[eksd <= as.Date("2013-02-01") & ENDDATE > as.Date("2013-02-01"), 
    sum(as.numeric(ENDDATE - as.Date("2013-02-01"))), keyby = ID][
      # chained with join to complete IDs
      .(ID = uid), on = "ID"][is.na(V1), V1 := 0][]
```

> ```
>    ID V1
> 1:  1 64
> 2:  2  0
> 3:  3 63
> ```

Answer (score 3):

For speed reason I would suggest that you stick with your first approach and simply add necessary zeros:

```
by_minem <- function(dt = lsr2) {
  x <- dt[eksd <= as.Date("2013-02-01") & ENDDATE > as.Date("2013-02-01"),
          sum(as.numeric(ENDDATE - as.Date("2013-02-01"))), keyby = ID]
  uid <- unique(dt$ID)
  id2 <- uid[!(uid %in% x$ID)]
  x2 <- data.table(ID = id2, V1 = 0)
  x <- rbind(x, x2)
  setkey(x, ID)
  x
}
by_minem(lsr)
#    ID V1
# 1:  1 64
# 2:  2  0
# 3:  3 63
```

Test on larger data:

```
#Create larger data:
n <- 5e4
lsr2 <- lapply(1:n, function(x) lsr)
lsr2 <- rbindlist(lsr2, use.names = T, fill = T, idcol = T)
lsr2[, ID := as.integer(paste0(.id, ID))]
lsr2[, .(.N, uniqueN(ID))]
#         N     V2
# 1: 400000 150000

by_henry <- function(dt = lsr2) {
  dt[, sum((eksd <= as.Date("2013-02-01") & ENDDATE > as.Date("2013-02-01")) *
            as.numeric(ENDDATE - as.Date("2013-02-01"))), keyby = ID]
}

system.time(r1 <- by_henry()) #92.53
system.time(r2 <- by_minem()) #21.73
92.53/21.73 #4 times faster
all.equal(r1, r2)
# [1] TRUE
```

### Update

And this would be even faster:

```
    by_minem2 <- function(dt = lsr2) {
  d <- as.numeric(as.Date("2013-02-01"))
  dt[, ENDDATE2 := as.numeric(ENDDATE)]
  x <- dt[eksd <= d & ENDDATE > d, sum(ENDDATE2 - d), keyby = ID]
  uid <- unique(dt$ID)
  id2 <- setdiff(uid, x$ID)
  id2 <- uid[!(uid %in% x$ID)]
  x2 <- data.table(ID = id2, V1 = 0)
  x <- rbind(x, x2)
  setkey(x, ID)
  x
}

system.time(r2 <- by_minem2()) #0.13
```

Comment: Very interesting. Perhaps you would consider that I need to repeat this for 200 different dates. Would you then write a for loop? I worked on this for Henrys answer: 
time.months <- as.Date("2013-02-01")+(365.25/12)*(0:10)

adhlist = data.table()

d <- as.Date("2013-02-01")

for (d in min(time.months):max(time.months)) {

  A <- cbind(d, lsr[, sum((eksd <= d & ENDDATE > d) *
            as.numeric(ENDDATE - d)), keyby = ID])
  adhlist <- rbind(adhlist, A)
  }

Comment: @Jakn09ab maybe you could create a new question about speeding up that loop... and copy the link here, in comment.

Comment: I just did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339884/building-efficient-for-loop-for-function I'll try to make the function work, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are removing all cases of `ID` being `2` in the selection process.

As an alternative you can put the selection inside the sum, for example

```
lsr[, sum((eksd <= as.Date("2013-02-01") & ENDDATE > as.Date("2013-02-01")) *
           as.numeric(ENDDATE - as.Date("2013-02-01"))), keyby = ID]
```

to give

```
   ID V1
1:  1 64
2:  2  0
3:  3 63
```

Comment: This is great. It works (though at 70 seconds). Would you care explaining to me what the star (*) does in the code?

Comment: @Jakn09ab It is simple multiplication.  The expression before the * is TRUE or FALSE, and gets coerced into 1 or 0 in the calculation.  The inefficiency here is that `as.numeric(ENDDATE - as.Date("2013-02-01"))` is calculated for the whole data table, not just the selected observations

Comment: haha. That's so obvious and wonderful. :-) Now I just need to figure out the for loop..