# building efficient for loop for user defined function: data.table

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I'm trying to build an efficient for loop for this function proposed by minem here: ([Data.table: how to get the blazingly fast subsets it promises and apply to a second data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263698/data-table-how-to-get-the-blazingly-fast-subsets-it-promises-and-apply-to-a-sec))

My data are:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

adherence <- cbind.data.frame(c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"), c("2013-01-01", "2013-01-01", "2013-01-01", "2013-02-01", "2013-02-01", "2013-02-01"))
names(adherence)[1] <- "ID" 
names(adherence)[2] <- "year"
adherence$year <- ymd(adherence$year)

lsr <- cbind.data.frame(
  c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3"), #ID
  c("2012-03-01", "2012-08-02", "2013-01-06","2012-08-25", "2013-03-22", "2013-09-15", "2011-01-01", "2013-01-05"), #eksd
  c("60", "90", "90", "60", "120", "60", "30", "90") # DDD
)
names(lsr)[1] <- "ID"
names(lsr)[2] <- "eksd"
names(lsr)[3] <- "DDD"

lsr$eksd <- as.Date((lsr$eksd))
lsr$DDD <- as.numeric(as.character(lsr$DDD))
lsr$ENDDATE <- lsr$eksd + lsr$DDD
lsr <- as.data.table(lsr)

adherence <- as.data.table(adherence)
```

The Function proposed by minem are:

```
by_minem2 <- function(dt = lsr2) {
  d <- as.numeric(as.Date("2013-02-01"))
  dt[, ENDDATE2 := as.numeric(ENDDATE)]
  x <- dt[eksd <= d & ENDDATE > d, sum(ENDDATE2 - d), keyby = ID]
  uid <- unique(dt$ID)
  id2 <- setdiff(uid, x$ID)
  id2 <- uid[!(uid %in% x$ID)]
  x2 <- data.table(ID = id2, V1 = 0)
  x <- rbind(x, x2)
  setkey(x, ID)
  x
}
```

This returns:

```
> by_minem2(lsr)
   ID V1
1:  1 64
2:  2  0
3:  3 63
```

For the loop i need to include information about which time I evaluated at so the ideal repeated output looks like this:

```
cbind(as.Date("2013-02-01"),by_minem2(lsr))
```

I then want to repeat this for different dates a few hundred times putting everything into the same data.table:

```
time.months <- as.Date("2013-02-01")+(365.25/12)*(0:192) #dates to evaluate at
```

I'm trying to do this with a for loop like this:

```
     for (d in min(time.months):max(time.months))
{
  by_minem <- function(dt = lsr2) {
    d <- as.numeric(d)
    dt[, ENDDATE2 := as.numeric(ENDDATE)]
    x <- dt[eksd <= d & ENDDATE > d, sum(ENDDATE2 - d), keyby = ID]
    uid <- unique(dt$ID)
    id2 <- setdiff(uid, x$ID)
    id2 <- uid[!(uid %in% x$ID)]
    x2 <- data.table(ID = id2, V1 = 0)
    x <- rbind(x, x2)
    setkey(x, ID)
    xtot <- append(xtot,x) 
    xtot <- cbind(d, xtot) # i need to know time of evaluation
    xtot
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the answer to the related question [Data.table: how to get the blazingly fast subsets it promises and apply to a second data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48263698/3817004), this can be solved by *updating in a non-equi join* which is possible with `data.table`.

The difference to the linked question is that here we need to create the cross join `CJ()` of all unique `ID`s with the vector of dates on our own before joining with `lsr`.

The OP has provided a series of dates `time.months` whose defintion

```
time.months <- as.Date("2013-02-01")+(365.25/12)*(0:192) #dates to evaluate at
```

leads to "crooked" dates which is only visible if coerced to numeric or POSIXct:

```
head(lubridate::as_datetime(time.months))
```

> ```
> [1] "2013-02-01 00:00:00 UTC" "2013-03-03 10:30:00 UTC" "2013-04-02 21:00:00 UTC"
> [4] "2013-05-03 07:30:00 UTC" "2013-06-02 18:00:00 UTC" "2013-07-03 04:30:00 UTC"
> ```

The issue is that these "dates" are not aligned with midnight but start somewhere during the day. To avoid these ambiguities, the `seq()` function can be used

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2013-02-01"), length.out = 193, by = "month")
```

which creates a series of dates starting on the first day of each month.

In addition, `data.table`'s `IDate` class is used which stores dates as integers (4 bytes) instead of double (8 bytes). This saves memory as well as processing time because the usually faster integer arithmetic can be used.

```
# coerce Date to IDate
idates <- as.IDate(dates)
setDT(lsr)[, eksd := as.IDate(eksd)][, ENDDATE := as.IDate(ENDDATE)]

# cross join unique IDs with dates 
CJ(ID = lsr$ID, date = idates, unique = TRUE)[
  # intialize result column
  , AH := 0L][
    # non-equi join and ...
    lsr, on = .(ID, date >= eksd, date < ENDDATE), 
    # ... update only matching rows
    AH := as.integer(ENDDATE - x.date)][
      # reshape from long to wide format
      , dcast(.SD, ID ~ date)]
```

> ```
>     ID 2013-02-01 2013-03-01 2013-04-01 2013-05-01 2013-06-01 2013-07-01 2013-08-01 [...]
> 1:  1         64         36          5          0          0          0          0
> 2:  2          0          0        110         80         49         19          0
> 3:  3         63         35          4          0          0          0          0
> ```

#### Caveat

Note that above code assumes that the intervals `[eksd, ENDDATE)` for each `ID` do *not* overlap. This can be verified by

```
lsr[order(eksd), all(eksd - shift(ENDDATE, fill = 0) > 0), keyby = ID]
```

> ```
>    ID   V1
> 1:  1 TRUE
> 2:  2 TRUE
> 3:  3 TRUE
> ```

In case there are overlaps, the above code can be modified to aggregate within the non-equi join using `by = .EACHI`.

#### Benchmark

In another related question [data.table by = xx How do i keep the groups of length 0 when i returns no match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48336742/3817004), the OP has pointed out that performance is crucial due to the size of his production data.

According to [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336742/data-table-by-xx-how-do-i-keep-the-groups-of-length-0-when-i-returns-no-match/48401280#comment83662275_48336742), *`lsr` has 20 mio rows and 12 columns, the `adherence` dataset, that I'm trying not to use has 1,5 mio rows of 2 columns.* In another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48263698/3817004), the OP mentions that *`lsr` is a few hundred mio. rows*.

@minem has responded to this by providing a benchmark in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48338949/3817004).  We can use this benchmark data to compare the different answers.

```
# create benchmark data
lsr <- data.frame(
  ID = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3"),
  eksd = as.Date(c("2012-03-01", "2012-08-02", "2013-01-06","2012-08-25", "2013-03-22", "2013-09-15", "2011-01-01", "2013-01-05")),
  DDD = as.integer(c("60", "90", "90", "60", "120", "60", "30", "90")),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
lsr$ENDDATE <- lsr$eksd + lsr$DDD
n <- 5e4
lsr2 <- lapply(1:n, function(x) lsr)
lsr2 <- rbindlist(lsr2, use.names = T, fill = T, idcol = T)
lsr2[, ID := as.integer(paste0(.id, ID))]
```

Thus, the benchmark dataset consists of 400 k rows and 150 k unique `ID`s:

```
lsr2[, .(.N, uniqueN(ID))]
```

> ```
>         N     V2
> 1: 400000 150000
> ```

```
# pull data preparation out of the benchmark 
lsr2i <- copy(lsr2)[, eksd := as.IDate(eksd)][, ENDDATE := as.IDate(ENDDATE)]
lsr2[, ENDDATE2 := as.numeric(ENDDATE)]

# define date series
dates <- seq(as.Date("2013-02-01"), length.out = 193, by = "month")
idates <- seq(as.IDate("2013-02-01"), length.out = 193, by = "month")

# run benchmark
library(microbenchmark)
bm <- microbenchmark(
  minem = {
    dt <- copy(lsr2)
    xtot <- lapply(dates, function(d) {
      d <- as.numeric(d)
      x <- dt[eksd <= d & ENDDATE > d, sum(ENDDATE2 - d), keyby = ID]
      uid <- unique(dt$ID)
      id2 <- setdiff(uid, x$ID)
      id2 <- uid[!(uid %in% x$ID)]
      if (length(id2) > 0) {
        x2 <- data.table(ID = id2, V1 = 0)
        x <- rbind(x, x2)
      }
      setkey(x, ID)
      x
    })
    for (x in seq_along(xtot)) {
      setnames(xtot[[x]], c("ID", paste0("V", x)))
    }
    xtot <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = "ID"), xtot)
    xtot
  },
  uwe = {
    dt <- copy(lsr2i)
    CJ(ID = dt$ID, date = idates, unique = TRUE)[, AH := 0L][
      dt, on = .(ID, date >= eksd, date < ENDDATE), 
      AH := as.integer(ENDDATE - x.date)][, dcast(.SD, ID ~ date)]
  },
  times = 1L
)
print(bm)
```

The result for one run shows that the *non-equi join* is more than 4 times faster than the `lapply()` approach.

> ```
> Unit: seconds
>   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
>  minem 27.654703 27.654703 27.654703 27.654703 27.654703 27.654703     1
>    uwe  5.958907  5.958907  5.958907  5.958907  5.958907  5.958907     1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

something like this :

```
dt <- lsr
dt[, ENDDATE2 := as.numeric(ENDDATE)]
s <- time.months
xtot <- lapply(s, function(d) {
  d <- as.numeric(d)
  x <- dt[eksd <= d & ENDDATE > d, sum(ENDDATE2 - d), keyby = ID]
  uid <- unique(dt$ID)
  id2 <- setdiff(uid, x$ID)
  id2 <- uid[!(uid %in% x$ID)]
  if (length(id2) > 0) {
    x2 <- data.table(ID = id2, V1 = 0)
    x <- rbind(x, x2)
  }
  setkey(x, ID)
  x
})
for (x in seq_along(xtot)) {
  setnames(xtot[[x]], c("ID", paste0("V", x)))
}

xtot <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = "ID"), xtot)
xtot
```

Comment: Let me understand this: The columns in the output besides ID (V1-V11) are the times evaluated at? so those names could be replaced, in the same order, as those in time.months? Why do you reassign? lsr and time.months?

Comment: @Jakn09ab Yes, each columns is `sum(ENDDATE2 - d)` for each date in `times.month`. You can replace the column names as you wish

Comment: I got some issues when implementing on my real data: uid <- unique(dt$ID was not an S4 class, but I just changed to bid <-  dt[,unique(ID)]. Then it worked using time.months of length 3. I'm running it now with full length, I'll check in a few hours and report any other adjustments necessary for implementing this on the full dataset, in case anyone tries to use this at a later time.